# Making paths in Ant script relative

Tags: java, ant

I am creating Ant xml file while generating the runnable jar of plugin.
As it is having all absolute path I want to make it relative. Because I want to add creation of jar as hudson job and automate it.

I am new to Ant scripting. So could anyone help me out. 
Few lines in the files look like below.

```
<Target>   
<zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="D:/00Tools/Catch_Plus_1.10.0/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20110423-0524.jar"/>
        <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="D:/00Tools/Tools_1.10.0/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20110321.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="D:/casdev/ffm-mks1/sw-tools-development/tools/plugins/com.xyz.tools.support/bin"/>
        <fileset dir="D:/casdev/ffm-mks1/sw-tools-development/tools/plugins/com.xyz.tools.extlib/bin"/>
        <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="D:/casdev/ffm-mks1/sw-tools-development/tools/plugins/com.xyz.tools.extlib/core/dbloggerclient.jar"/>

</Target>
```

I want this to be relative to my hudson job.

Answer (score 0):

Set the optional ${basedir} property of the project element and put your paths in relative to the basedir.
Besides, use  to check the properties.